# How can I make multiple buttons to change a different div background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Take a look at what I am trying to make: 
https://codepen.io/SomeRandomGuy0/pen/aWvGxO

I was able to make the color of the square change color using the button "Blue". What I want to do is make multiple buttons to change the color of the square to what it says in the button. For example if I clicked on a button that says "Green", the square will turn green and if I clicked on another button that says "Purple", it will turn purple.

I am getting introduced to DOM in JavaScript so sorry for such a basic question.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <title>DOM Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = 'square'></div>
    <button onClick = changeColor() >Blue</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
#square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function changeColor(){
  var elem = document.getElementById( 'square' );
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the color as parameter on calling function at button

check this code pen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRoPJo

```
    <button onClick = changeColor('Blue') >Blue</button>
    <button onClick = changeColor('green') >green</button>
    <button onClick = changeColor('yellow') >yellow</button>
```

**JS**

```
    function changeColor(color){
     var elem = document.getElementById( 'square' );
     elem.style.backgroundColor =color;  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the codepen. It gaved me a good visual of what it should look like.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach could be to update `changeColor()` to take an argument of `color`.
So for example,

Javascript:

```
function changeColor(color){
  var elem = document.getElementById( 'square' );
  elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Then in the HTML we could do:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <title>DOM Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = 'square'></div>
    <button onClick = changeColor('blue') >Blue</button>
    <button onClick = changeColor('red') >Red</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will allow us to generalize the `changeColor()` function, and make it more reusable for future applications!

Comment: Wow. I never really thought about this. This worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if/else statement in your function, I'm not going to do it for you, but the logic should be, if blue button is clicked, change to blue, if red button is clicked change to red and so on.

Comment: 'if' and 'else' are useful - but without any 'isClicked' / this answer is not really an answer. The OP is new*

Answer (score 0):

data-attributes are great for this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/0hm9wnk7/  I also like to use `rel` to hook the js into the markup instead of classes to keep things really clear.

```
<div class='square' rel='box'></div>

<ul class='color-list' rel='box-colors'>
 <li class='color' data-color='red'>red</li>
 <li class='color' data-color='blue'>blue</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

...

```
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.color-list .color {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

...

```
// $('selector/element') - 'queries'(looks for) for the object in the DOM / j-'query' get it?
// var $thing (with $sign is just a convention to remind you that it's a jQuery object / that comes with some jQuery specific stuff)
var $box = $('[rel="box"]'); // cache the element with rel='box' to a pointer(variable) for use later
var $boxColors = $('[rel="box-colors"]'); // same idea
var $colorTriggers = $boxColors.find('.color'); // same idea / see .find() method

$colorTriggers.on('click', function() { 
  // .on() is a method for attaching event handlers - in this case, 'click'
  thisColor = $(this).data('color'); // get the clicked element's data-attr for data-color
  $box.css('background', thisColor); // set the box css background to the color you just retrieved from the data-attr
});
```

Comment: I don't know any jQuery yet so this is kind of confusing

Comment: I'll add some comments, but I wrote it this way to keep it simple. :0

Comment: You can look at this: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/  and try it without the jQuery methods and see which you like better.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT -- this approach is simplest IMO

[Codepen DEMO](https://codepen.io/presstep/pen/dWYQer)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <title>DOM Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id='preview'></div>
    <input id="colorpicker" type="color" />
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
  const picker = document.getElementById('colorpicker');
  preview.style.backgroundColor = picker.value;
  picker.addEventListener('input', e => {
    preview.style.backgroundColor = e.currentTarget.value
  })
})
```

### ORIGINAL -- an excuse to play with css vars

Here's an approach:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
const getRandomColor = () => colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
const selectColor = (color) => document.body.style.setProperty('--current', color);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  
  const preview = document.getElementById('square');
  const changeColor = (e) => {
    let color = getComputedStyle(e.currentTarget).getPropertyValue('--color-name');
    
    selectColor(color);
    
    let logStyles = ` 
      color: black; 
      font-weight: bold; 
      background-color: ${color};
      font-size: 18px;`;
                        
    
    console.log(`color changed to %c ${color} `, logStyles);
  }

  // 1. select purple for starting color
  // 2. create buttons
  // NOTE: I created the buttons programatically, but you could just as easily
  // 
  //  <button style="--color-name:red;">red</button>
  //  <button style="--color-name:orange;">orange</button>
  //  etc...
  
  selectColor('rebeccapurple')
  colors.forEach((color, i) => {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.style.setProperty('--color-name', color);
    button.onclick = changeColor;
    button.textContent = color;
    document.body.appendChild(button);
  })

})
```

```css
body {
    --current: 'green';
  }
#square{
  background-color: var(--current);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  color: var(--color-name);
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <title>DOM Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id = 'square'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```